# Scala calculate the total quantity of the same products

Tags: scala, collections

I have a List collection below:

PO_ID | Product_ID | Name   | Qty 
PO123 | P001       | Item 1 | 10  
PO123 | P001       | Item 1 | 10  
PO123 | P002       | Item 2 | 30  
PO123 | P002       | Item 2 | 10

How can I convert it to be like the collection below:

PO_ID | Product_ID | Name   | Qty 
PO123 | P001       | Item 1 | 20  
PO123 | P002       | Item 2 | 40

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand how your "Map" is defined, it definitely looks more like a List to me.

Here is how you can do it with a List, if you want to do it with a Map you will just have to tweak the code a little as the functions used below are all inherited from the iterable base class (common to map and list).

```
val data = List(("PO123", "P001", "Item 1", 10),
                ("PO123", "P001", "Item 1", 10),
                ("PO123", "P002", "Item 2", 30),
                ("PO123", "P002", "Item 2", 10))

 data.groupBy( product => (product._1, product._2, product._3))
      .map {
         case (productInfo, products) => {
         val total = products.foldLeft(0)((sum,elt) => sum + elt._4)
         (productInfo._1,productInfo._2,productInfo._3,total)
          }
 }
```

Result of this would be:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(String, String, String, Int)] =
    List((PO123,P001,Item 1,20), (PO123,P002,Item 2,40))
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to have sth like

```
case class Document(poID: String, productID: String, name: String, qty: Int)
```

then you could

```
var list2 = list.groupBy(doc => doc.productID)
```

that gives you Map[String, List[Document]]. now you can map it with:

```
list2.map(stringListTuple => stringListTuple._2.foldLeft(Document("","","",0)){
   (acc: Document,curr: Document) => Document(curr.poID, curr.productID, curr.name,curr.qty + acc.qty)
}).toList.sortBy(el => el.productID)
```

It works but I am sure you can do it prettier :)

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
val in = Array(("PO123", "P001", "Item 1", 10), ("PO123", "P001", "Item 1", 10),
               ("PO123", "P002", "Item 2", 30), ("PO123", "P002", "Item 2", 10))
```

Then

```
in groupBy (p=>(p._1,p._2,p._3)) map { case(k,v) => 
  (k._1, k._2, k._3, (v map (_._4) sum )) }
```

which returns

```
List((PO123,P001,Item 1,20), (PO123,P002,Item 2,40))
```

Note that `v map (_._4)` extracts the quantities onto a list so that we can sum them up without folding.